# Laravel Validaton based on custom function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form to create schedules for a rooms. I want to validate if the data range is overlaped with other schedules. I created a helper (TimeHelpers::checkOverlap($start,$end)) which do that but I don't know how to integrate it in a laravel validation. Can I create a custom validator calling that helper?

Comment: rather than using helper function you should go with custom validation https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [manually create a Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) in your controller, and have it validated in the [after validation hook](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#after-validation-hook):

```php
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    // other things you are validating
])->after(function ($validator) use ($request) {
    // assuming you have `start` and `end` passed in the request
    if (TimeHelpers::checkOverlap($request->start, $request->end)) {
        $validator->errors()->add('schedule_overlap', 'There is a scheduling conflict for selected dates');
    }
})->validate();
```

If you're using [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#after-validation-hook), you would put it in the `withValidator` method, as in:

```php
public function withValidator(Validator $validator): void
{
    $validator->after(function (Validator $validator) {
        if (TimeHelpers::checkOverlap($this->start, $this->end)) {
            $validator->errors()->add('schedule_overlap', 'There is a scheduling conflict for selected dates');
        }
    });
}
```

If this is something you use in multiple places throughout the app, you can wrap it in the [Custom Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).